# Remove/minimize Git merge conflicts

Tags: c++, git

I am trying to think of a way to completely remove or minimize Git merge conflicts for the following scenario:

```
switch(value)
{
    case OLD_CASE_1:
    case OLD_CASE_2:
    case NEW_CASE_1:
    case NEW_CASE_2:
    case NEW_CASE_3:
    case NEW_CASE_4:
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

For each of the new cases, I create a branch where I add just the case specific to that branch. (Eg. `feature/new-case-x` contains just `case NEW_CASE_X:`).

At the end of the day, I submit 4 pull requests. As soon as any one of them is merged, the others will enter a conflict state. Since the case order doesn't matter to me, is there a way I can minimize or completely get rid of conflicts? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think so. Git is language agnostic. It has no way of knowing your intent in C++. I'll wait for somebody more knowledgeable than me to prove me wrong :)

Comment: If case list is long enough, you might separate new cases with 3 lines or more (size of diff context).

Comment: I assume in reality youir cases are not sequential numbers? :-)

Comment: @GemTaylor No, just text. XD

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to do an immediate check-in/promotion with a marker label after creating the named test branch.

The creation of the marker label may be as trivial as a comment, or a pair of comments, so would avoid needing a test cycle before promotion. Perhaps use the branch name to "decorate" the comment. By immediately, I do mean it! So long as 2 new test branches are not both created simultaneously in this small window, they now each have a space to actually write their code that should be conflict free.

You could do the same with the test body, if you have issues with people simultaneously appending tests in existing files: Create a comment block denoting the start and end of their test. So long as they write between the lines a conflict is avoided. This does mean they have to choose which test module they want to append to straight away, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  As [R Sahu noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775657/remove-minimize-git-merge-conflicts#comment100107009_56775657), Git has no idea about the *semantics* of the text it is merging.  It merely treats it as a set of lines.  If, while merging two different change-sets, the lines overlap or abut, you get a merge conflict.  For instance, given:

```
      case OLD_CASE_1:
      case OLD_CASE_2:
+     case NEW_CASE_1:
          return true;
```

vs

```
      case OLD_CASE_1:
      case OLD_CASE_2:
+     case NEW_CASE_2:
          return true;
```

Git would in general declare a conflict here.  Were this Go code, rather than C++, Git would be "more right" about this being a true conflict, since Go has no automatic fall-through (or equivalently, has the C++ equivalent of a default `break;` in front of each `case`), i.e., in C++ the semantics would be to return true *only* for the one new case, and no longer for `OLD_CASE_2`.

Now, if you're in a group that prefers to *rebase* pull requests, your automatic rebasing will tend to go smoothly *if* the `NEW_CASE_1` PR is accepted and merged first *and* you build your second PR *on* the first one *and* you rebase each of your remaining PRs on the accepted PRs in order.  This is more complicated, and prone to a lot more re-work if your PRs must be accepted in some other order for some reason, but sometimes it's pretty nice.  Whether you and/or your group want to do this is a much bigger question, though.